# What is the %u command in all my programs command?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, ubuntu-10.04

I saw in my programs properties they have a "%u" in the end of the command, what does this do?
Using Ubuntu 10.04.

e.g. My Chrome have the command: /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome %U
for what this %u is used here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you associate a file with a command, you can call this command with several arguments. %u simply means that the file name should go there. It is useful so you can put arguments after the filename. There are several other flags you can use.

Comment: `%u` is the GNOME's file URI (such as `file:///etc/motd` or `sftp://foohost/home/tom/file.txt`). `%s` would get you the "normal" file path.

Answer (score 0):

`%u` is used in Java's FileHandler to generate a unique field value.

From http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/logging/FileHandler.html

> A pattern consists of a string that
>   includes the following special
>   components that will be replaced at
>   runtime:
>
> ```
> * "/" the local pathname separator
> * "%t" the system temporary directory
> * "%h" the value of the "user.home" system property
> * "%g" the generation number to distinguish rotated logs
> * "%u" a unique number to resolve conflicts
> * "%%" translates to a single percent sign "%"
> ```

Does that make sense in your particular context?

Comment: Its not just in java programs that the %u appears