# What does "sudo /bin/ls %s %foo" mean?

Tags: sudo

I am trying to understand the above command.

```
sudo /bin/ls %s %file_path
```

1. What is does `%` do? Is it some kind of substituting mechanism?
2. What does `sudo /bin/ls` do?

Comment: What's the context of this? You see this inside some Java code? (Since you're @JavaDeveloper)

Comment: Well... http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe

Comment: In any case: https://www.sudo.ws/man/sudo.man.html http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html

Comment: Sounds like you're misreading and misinterpreting some python. `"sudo /bin/ls %s" % foo` would be a sensible piece of python involving a format string that *outputs* a shell command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

% in bash scripting stands for anchoring, but it can sometimes vary between programs what it does as a [part of some parameter](https://superuser.com/questions/138433/what-is-the-u-command-in-all-my-programs-command) or [another](http://docs.xfce.org/_media/xfce/thunar/1.6/thunar_create-action-dialog.png). For **ls** it does nothing. For sudo it does some things, but not in this context; it is making no sense to me... this command simply tries to (as root; for the record, you almost never have to run **ls** as root, there are very few places where filenames can not be accessed by normal users through **ls**) search directories %s and %foo for files, and should give us the result of "ls cannot access %s: No such file or directory" and much the same for %foo. (There can never be directory %s unless you created it)

For scripting it does the below.

From http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe:

**Anchoring** Additionally you can "anchor" an expression: A # (hashmark) will indicate that your expression is matched against the beginning portion of the string, a % (percent-sign) will do it for the end portion.

```
MYSTRING=xxxxxxxxxx
echo ${MYSTRING/#x/y}  # RESULT: yxxxxxxxxx
echo ${MYSTRING/%x/y}  # RESULT: xxxxxxxxxy
```

(What the code is doing is that it is trading either the first or the last "x" out for an "y")